# Javascript usages of bind vs curry*?

Tags: javascript, currying

I'm trying to understand the difference between `curry` vs `bind`.

The implementation of `bind` is :

```
/*1*/   Function.prototype.bind = function ()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/        var fn = this,
/*4*/           args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
/*5*/       var object = args.shift();
/*6*/       return function ()
/*7*/       {
/*8*/           return fn.apply(object, 
/*9*/                           args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))
/*10*/       };
/*11*/   }
```

The implementation of `curry` is :

```
/*1*/   Function.prototype.curry = function ()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/       var fn = this,
/*4*/           args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
/*5*/       return function ()
/*6*/       {
/*7*/           return fn.apply(this, 
/*8*/                           args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
/*9*/       };
/*10*/   };
```

I already know that `curry` is not an internal function (unlike `bind` which is in IE9+). But still:

Why do  I hear people keep talking about `curry`  , While they can simply use `bind` operation ?

The only difference is the context which is actually found only at the `bind`  function.

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvK0d.jpg)

[image]

Example :

Let's say I have this function :

```
function add(x,y,z)
{
  return x+y+z;
}
```

I could do it with `curry` :

```
alert(add.curry(2).curry(1)(4)) //7
```

But I could also do it with :

```
alert(add.bind(undefined,2).bind(undefined,1)(4)) //7
```

I don't understand why this `curry` term function exists while it is possible   to add a dummy context to the bind function.

What am I missing ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m, `curry` does not exist. Googling `Javascript curry` turns up no results for browsers offering it as an extension. Where is this function coming from? Are you using an external library?

Comment: @user2357112 I didnt say it's suppose to be in browser

Comment: Then where are you running this? You don't mention node.js or any other particular environment. (node.js doesn't seem to have a `curry` method either.)

Comment: @user2357112 there are many discussions about curry/partial in javascript arena. Im just asking why we need curry if we could easily do it via bind. that's all

Comment: I don't understand your question. `bind` is used to bind functions to contexts and `curry` to create partially applied functions. They have a different usage and the simple fact that you can use `bind` with `undefined` for currying doesn't mean that you should, because you're obfuscating your code.

Comment: You're questioning why the term "curry" exists simply because JavaScript has a `.bind()` function? I really don't understand what you're getting at. Many functional programming concepts existed before JS had `.bind()`, and in fact before JS existed. Should they now cease to exist?

Comment: @cookiemonster Well , That's an answer too. While I was reading john resigs book ,  I found the terms bind/curry/partial and I just asked why did he want  to show the curry implementation while bind is already there. ( he mentioned bind and after 2 paragraph , he mentioned curry) that's all.

Comment: If you're more generally wondering about the origins of the terms, and why JS's method is called `.bind()` instead of `curry()`, I would guess that it's because `.bind()` does give you the option to bind the `this` value, which doesn't really have anything to with currying. I believe that was the main purpose of `.bind()`, since the `this` value changes so dynamically, and can be a pain to deal with in callback functions. I think the idea of `.bind()` may have come from the `prototypejs` library, but I'm not totally sure about that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`bind` forces you to attach a context to the function, while by using `curry`, you can delay the specification of function context until **invoking** the curried function, useful in many cases.
consider the following example (not the perfect one, just to illustrate the idea):

```
function Query(sessionKey, dataBuilder) {
  this.sessionKey = sessionKey;
  this.url = "http://www.example.com/search";
  this.dataBuilder = dataBuilder
  this.search = function (term) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.url,
      data: this.dataBuilder(term);
    })
  }
}

function dataBuilder(entity, query) {
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
    'entity': entity,
    'searchTerm': query
    'session': this.sessionKey // will be always undefined if bind(undefined,...) is used
  });
  return payload
}
var bindEx= dataBuilder.bind(undefined, "username");
var curryEx= dataBuilder.curry("username");

var usernameQuery = new Query("id1234",bindEx); // won't work, this.sessionKey will be undefined
usernameQuery = new Query("id1234",curryEx); // will  work, this.sessionKey will be id1234 in the DataBuilder
```

Answer (score 23):

There is a difference in intention.

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is to reduce the number of arguments, usually to avoid calling a function a lot with the same initial arguments. For example:

```
var celsiusToKelvin = add.curry(273.15);
```

[bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is to make sure that a function is attached to an object. It also happens to offer a currying facility, so yes you can use bind() to curry(), but if you want to curry, curry() has fewer arguments and shows your intention.

Comment: I agree it is about intention.  To put it another way, `bind` *closes* the function, while `curry` leaves it open.  Of course, as the OP observes, the operations are practically identical, and you can close a function with `curry` by binding all of its arguments.  But the general assumption is that a curried function will not be invoked by itself, whereas a bound function will.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think it has something to do with compatibility with older browsers as bind is only available since ECMAScript 5.

See this for a list of `.bind()` support: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Also from what I've heard, most people still use curry because it looks cleaner as it doesn't need that extra `undefined` in the arguments.

Comment: Implementations of curry can also include both syntax sugar (no curriedFunc(3,4)(2), just curriedFunc(3,4,2) ) and also options to close the function to a set number of arguments (what was originally defined or an arbitrary number set at curry definition time).