# Refactoring: Anonymous functions to named functions, parameter reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i am having a bit of Dilemma, trying to refactor a set of nested anonymous closures in Javascript. However i am unsure the standard way of maintaining reference to parameters that otherwise would be seen by child closures.

for example

```
var foo;
var obj = new Obj();
obj.foobar(function (p1, p2, p3) {
    foo.onEvent(function (s1, s2) {
         if (s1 === 'bar') {
              s2.status = p2; //p2 has a reference here
         }
    });  
});
```

However if i refactor this code, so each closure it on its own named function, What would be the ideal way of getting a reference to p2?

example

```
var onFooEvent = function (s1, s2) {
             if (s1 === 'bar') {
                  s2.status = p2; //p2 will no longer has a reference here
             }
        }; 

var onFoobar = function (p1, p2, p3) {
        foo.onEvent(onFooEvent); 
    };

var foo;
var obj = new Obj();
obj.foobar(onFoobar);
```

MORE ROBUST EXAMPLE

```
var pooledQuery = function (query, params, env, res) {
    return new imports.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pool.acquire(function (err, client) {
            var db;
            if (err != null) {
                console.log(err)
                reject(err);
            }
            var meta = { env: env, res: res, result: [] };                

            db = client.query(query, params);
            db.on('result', function (res) {
                return res.on('row', function (row) {
                    return meta.result.push(row);
                }).on('error', function (err) {
                    meta.result = err;
                    reject(meta);
                }).on('end', function (info) {
                    return meta.result;
                });
            }).on('end', function () {
                pool.release(client);
                resolve(meta);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Either you set it to a global variable or you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with leaving them nested if they need to access closure variables. You can still name them.

Comment: Where is that `foo` coming from?

Comment: What promise library are you using? It looks like you could improve your promise patterns. There's nothing wrong with your closures.

Comment: @Bergi i was told to refactor all closures to named functions :-| i am using bluebird for `Promise`

Comment: i am trying to see if this https://hughfdjackson.com/javascript/why-curry-helps/ adds any value to solve this problem.

Comment: @DevZer0: Just [name them](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/). You don't need to move them elsewhere. Regardless, if you feel you must do that have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) where I detail the two stages of unnesting.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your input, i solved the problem using `bind` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a curried function into `foo.onEvent` (and additionally change the arguments that `onFooEvent` accepts) -- something like this:

```
var onFooEvent = function (pArgs, s1, s2) {
  if (s1 === 'bar') {
    s2.status = pArgs[1]; 
  }
}; 

var onFoobar = function (p1, p2, p3) {
  foo.onEvent(_.curry(onFooEvent)(arguments)); 
};
```

here's a contrived runnable example:

```
var _ = require('lodash')

var print_stuff = function (p_args, s1, s2) {
  console.log(p_args[0])
  console.log(p_args[1])
  console.log(p_args[2])
  console.log(s1)
  console.log(s2)
}

var do_theoretical_stuff = function (p1, p2, p3) {
  return _.curry(print_stuff)(arguments)
}

var do_actual_stuff = do_theoretical_stuff(1, 2, 3) 

do_actual_stuff('a', 'b')
```

which outputs to the console:

```
1
2
3
a
b
```

**Update:**  really great point made below about `bind`. the difference between `bind` and `_.curry` is that with bind you must set a context (via the first argument) at the time you use it. bind is basically doing two things for you: 1) setting context (i.e., explicitly binding/defining what `this` will actually be inside the function now rather than when the function is invoked) *and* 2) doing what curry does. if you don't need or want the first feature, then i think a cleaner approach is to use curry. (if you don't normally use a library like lodash, it's easy to find a standalone curry function that can be added to one's local utils.) this SO question has more on the topic: [Javascript 's bind vs curry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127889/javascript-s-bind-vs-curry)

Comment: if you are working with an external library where event callback functions already have set of pre-defined arguments, how can it be modified? 

i pasted a an actual example

Comment: so if you need to pass in a callback function to `pool.acquire` and that callback's arguments are only `err` and `client`, then *you* would write a function elsewhere called, say, `foo` that takes 6 arguments, `query, params, env, res, err, client`, and then the callback function that you explicitly pass into `pool.acquire` would be a function that is a currying of `foo`  w.r.t. to the first four arguments, like this: `pool.acquire(_.curry(foo)(query)(params)(env)(res));`

Comment: i was able to solve my issue using `bind()` i don't know what's the advantage of using `curry`

Comment: i +1 your answer for the approach. However i prefer the `bind` method. If you write a bit of a detailed answer covering `bind` and explaning why `curry` maybe better than `bind` i will accept your answer.

Comment: great point, i have added some notes comparing bind and curry

Comment: thanks. it was an interesting question for me to think about :)

Answer (score 1):

here is how i solved in using `bind`, there is bit more refactoring here where i plan to encapsulate all the functions inside another class instance. (However ignore that part) Just wanted to share how i solved it.

```
var DbPool = function () {

};

DbPool.prototype.onRow = function (meta, row) {
    return meta.result.push(row);
};

var onRowError = function (meta, reject, err) {
    meta.result = err;
    reject(meta);
};

var onRowEnd = function (meta, info) {
    return meta.result;
};

var onResult = function (meta, reject, res) {

    var onRowBind = DbPool.prototype.onRow.bind(this, meta);
    var onRowErrorBind = onRowError.bind(this, meta, reject);
    var onRowEndBind = onRowEnd.bind(this, meta);

    return res.on('row', onRowBind).on('error', onRowErrorBind).on('end', onRowEndBind);
};

var onEnd = function (meta, resolve, client) {
    pool.release(client);
    resolve(meta);
};

var dbPoolAcquired = function (query, params, env, res, resolve, reject, err, client) {
    var db;
    if (err != null) {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err);
    }
    var meta = { env: env, res: res, result: [] };

    logger.debug("Query %s Params %s", query, params);

    db = client.query(query, params);

    var onResultBind = onResult.bind(this, meta, reject);
    var onEndBind = onEnd.bind(this, meta, resolve, client);

    db.on('result', onResultBind).on('end', onEndBind);
};

var dbPoolPromised = function(query, params, env, res, resolve, reject) {
    var dbPoolAcquiredBind = dbPoolAcquired.bind(undefined, query, params, env, res, resolve, reject)
    pool.acquire(dbPoolAcquiredBind);
};

var pooledQuery = function (query, params, env, res) {
    var dbPoolPromisedBind = dbPoolPromised.bind(this, query, params, env, res);
    return new imports.promise(dbPoolPromisedBind);
};
```